# Manually arrange the order of photos in an album?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

**Preface**: This may *not* be a well-suited *question* according to the policy. If anyone happens to know the workaround(s) please share your insight; otherwise we can just discuss how it can be done and/or eventually file a request to the officials.

Orders of the photos can be rearranged (by dragging and dropping) if accessing from the Facebook website. My project supports members (login via Facebook) to upload photos to the App Page, its album(s) to be specific, which, so far everything seems to be working. However, when members upload photos using their smart devices:

- they might not select the files in order or
- they might wanna rearrange the orders after uploading

Although I understand the fact that ordering of photos could be sorted by `created_time`, `updated_time` and/or even the not-so-well-documented `backdated_time` fields, we as the dev team believe the need to order regardless of `*_time` fields would come in handy to our members.

So, is there any official way or undocumented workaround (such as hidden fields when making API call) we can accomplish this!?